# ASP.Net SPA Project Template 2.0.0 does not have aspnet-webpack module

Tags: webpack, asp.net-core, asp.net-spa

I'm migrating my ASP.Net Core Angular project to use Microsoft.DotNet.Web.Spa.ProjectTemplates 2.0.0, which uses Angular 5.

When running on Development Mode, I get an error saying:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.HostingModels.NodeInvocationException:
>   Webpack dev middleware failed because of an error while loading
>   'aspnet-webpack'. Error was: Error: Cannot find module 'aspnet-webpack

Was aspnet-webpack replaced by something else in this new template? Why is my app looking for it?

I tried installing it with 'npm i -save aspnet-webpack' but I still get the same error.

Comment: Try completely removing the node_modules folder, and re-installing with npm install.

Comment: What version of Webpack are you using?